# How to find the "lexical file" in Wordnet?

Tags: sparql, wordnet

If you look at the [original Wordnet search](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=filling&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=1&h=100) and select "Display options: Show Lexical File Info", you'll see an extremely useful classification of words called **lexical file**. Eg for "filling" we have:

```
   <noun.substance>S: (n) filling, fill (any material that fills a space or container)
   <noun.process>S: (n) filling (flow into something (as a container))
   <noun.food>S: (n) filling (a food mixture used to fill pastry or sandwiches etc.)
   <noun.artifact>S: (n) woof, weft, filling, pick (the yarn woven across the warp yarn in weaving)
   <noun.artifact>S: (n) filling ((dentistry) a dental appliance consisting of ...)
   <noun.act>S: (n) filling (the act of filling something)
```

The first thing in brackets is the "lexical file". Unfortunately I have not been able to find a SPARQL endpoint that provides this info

- The [latest RDF translation](http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/lod/wn30/%20includes) of Wordnet 3.0 points to two things:
- [Talis SPARQL endpoint](http://api.talis.com/stores/wordnet/services/sparql). Use eg this query to check there's no such info:

  `DESCRIBE <http://purl.org/vocabularies/princeton/wn30/synset-chair-noun-1>`
- [W3C's mapping description](http://www.w3.org/TR/wordnet-rdf/).  Appendix D "Conversion details" describes something useful: `wn:classifiedByTopic`. 
  But it's not the same as **lexical file**, and is quite incomplete. Eg "chair" has nothing, while one of the senses of "completion" is in the topic "American Football"

  `DESCRIBE <http://purl.org/vocabularies/princeton/wn30/synset-completion-noun-1>` ->

  `<j.1:classifiedByTopic rdf:resource="http://purl.org/vocabularies/princeton/wn30/synset-American_football-noun-1"/>`

The question: is there a public Wordnet query API, or a database, that provides the **lexical file** information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done through **MIT JWI** (MIT Java Wordnet Interface) a Java API to query Wordnet. There's a topic in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525372/mit-java-wordnet-interface-getting-wordnet-lexicographer-classes-or-super-sense) showing how to implement a java class to access lexicographic

Comment: BTW, if you are interested in those lexicographics, search on the web for two papers by Ciaramita and Johnson and Ciaramita and Altun, which describer the proposal of Wordnet Supersenses (which are the lexicographics)

Answer (score 7):

Using the Python NLTK interface:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

for synset in wn.synsets('can'):
    print  synset.lexname
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can find it in the RDF/OWL Representation of WordNet. It's in the WordNet distribution though: `dict/lexnames`. Here is the content of the file as of WordNet 3.0:

```
00      adj.all 3
01      adj.pert        3 
02      adv.all 4
03      noun.Tops       1  
04      noun.act        1
05      noun.animal     1
06      noun.artifact   1
07      noun.attribute  1
08      noun.body       1
09      noun.cognition  1
10      noun.communication      1
11      noun.event      1
12      noun.feeling    1
13      noun.food       1
14      noun.group      1
15      noun.location   1
16      noun.motive     1
17      noun.object     1
18      noun.person     1
19      noun.phenomenon 1
20      noun.plant      1
21      noun.possession 1
22      noun.process    1
23      noun.quantity   1
24      noun.relation   1
25      noun.shape      1
26      noun.state      1
27      noun.substance  1
28      noun.time       1
29      verb.body       2
30      verb.change     2
31      verb.cognition  2
32      verb.communication      2
33      verb.competition        2
34      verb.consumption        2
35      verb.contact    2
36      verb.creation   2
37      verb.emotion    2
38      verb.motion     2
39      verb.perception 2
40      verb.possession 2
41      verb.social     2
42      verb.stative    2
43      verb.weather    2
44      adj.ppl 3
```

For each entry of dict/data.*, the second number is the lexical file info. For example, this filling entry contains the number 13, which is noun.food.

```
07883031 13 n 01 filling 0 002 @ 07882497 n 0000 ~ 07883156 n 0000 | a food mixture used to fill pastry or sandwiches etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me,

```
Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(wordStr);

ReferenceSynset referenceSynset = (ReferenceSynset) synsets[i];

int lexicalCode =referenceSynset.getLexicalFileNumber();
```

Then use above table to deduce "lexnames" e.g. noun.time

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, chances are it is in your appdata, in the local directory. To get there, you will want to open your file browser, go to the top, and type in %appdata%

Next click on roaming, and then find the nltk_data directory. In there, you will have your corpora file. The full path is something like: 
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\corpora

and lexnames will present under 
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\corpora\wordnet.